# iMovie - when selecting crop controls, no adjustable frame appears

Tags: video, imovie, crop

I'm trying to crop a clip in my iMovie project.

After I select cropping controls, whether I'm using "Fit" or "Crop to Fill" or "Ken Burns" there's no white adjustable frame like I see in many of the how to videos.

Has that feature been removed? **How do I access the cropping frame?**

Answer (score 0):

The cropping frame appears only in "Crop to fill" and "Ken Burns" modes; not in "Fit". I am using the latest version of iMovie with macOS Monterey and the frame is there as in earlier versions.